# Getting 422 Unprocessable Entity error when search bar ind frontend is null - How to catch it?

Tags: html, fastapi, htmx

I have a search bar as my frontend with an input field

Together with HTMX and FastAPI
I can search an fetch user information from a static List with dictionaries of user information inside.

I would like it to be as dynamic as possible.
so the results updates as i'm typing, fetching user information works pretty well.
But when i delete whatever string i had in my search bar, the previous results stay and i get a

> "POST /search HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity

Untill i enter something else that matches my user list.

I'm trying to figure how to catch that error, and send an html response to the front.
Or for my search logic to work with a null string.

```
@app.post('/search', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def search(request: Request, hx_request: Optional[str] = Header(None), search: str = Form()):
    search.lower()
    print(f'search is: {search}')
    
    try:
        if search == "":
            raise HTTPException(status_code=422, detail="No search term or no results")

        #return HTMLResponse('<td>No Results</td>')
        print(f'search is: {search}')
        
        search_results = list(filter(lambda user: user['name'].lower().find(search) != -1 or user['email'].lower().find(search) != -1, data_users))
        
        #await asyncio.sleep(1)
        search_result_html = "".join(
            f"""
            <tr>
                <td><div class="my-4 p-2">{user['name']}</div></td>
                <td><div class="my-4 p-2">{user['email']}</div></td>
            </tr>
            """
            for user in search_results
        )
        context = {'request': request, 'result': search_result_html}
        if hx_request:
            return HTMLResponse(content=search_result_html, status_code=200)
        else:
            return temp.TemplateResponse('search.html', context)
    except HTTPException as e:
        error_html = '<td>No Results</td>'
        return HTMLResponse(content=error_html, status_code=e.status_code)
```

HTML input field with HTMX:

```
<input
        class="border border-gray-600 bg-gray-800 p-2 rounded-lg w-full mb-5"
        type="search"
        name="search"
        placeholder="Begin Typing To Search Users..."
        hx-post="/search"
        hx-trigger="input changed delay:500ms, search"
        hx-target="#search-results"
        hx-indicator="#loading"
        />
        <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
            <thead class="bg-gray-800 text-white">
                <tr>
                    <th name="name" scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-center text-xs font-medium uppercase-tracking-wider">Name</th>
                    <th name="email" scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-center text-xs font-medium uppercase-tracking-wider">Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="search-results" class="divide-y divide-gray-600">
                <!-- Search results go here -->
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the function argument `Form` to accept empty inputs, by default it does not do so. Two options would be to allow `Form("")` or `Form(None)`, here is an example using the latter:

```py
@app.post("/search", response_model=dict, status_code=200)
async def search(request: Request, search: Optional[str] = Form(None)):
    if search is None:
        # handle this...
        return {"message": None}
    search.lower()
    print(f"search is: {search}")
    return {"message": search}

# test the endpoint
response = requests.post(url, data={"search": None})
response.statuc_code, response.text
>>> (200, '{"message":null}')

# also accepts empty strings as an argument
response = requests.post(url, data={"search": ""})
response.statuc_code, response.text
>>> (200, '{"message":null}')
```

See also the discussion [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/854).

Comment: Wauw that was easy totally solved my problem.
thank you very much!